# browserifyでまとめたモジュールをHTMLのインラインスクリプトから実行したい

Tags: browserify, requirejs

webサイトの開発で、browserifyを使って複数の自作JSモジュールを一つにバンドルしています。
それをHTMLのscriptタグで読み込むと意図する通りスクリプトが実行されます。

```
<script src="application.js"></script>
```

しかし、HTMLのインラインスクリプトから個々の自作JSモジュールを
読み込む方法がわかりません。

```
<script src="application.js"></script>
<script>
  var mymodule = require("mymodule");
  new mymodule("<?php echo $hoge; ?>");
</script>
```

とすると、

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

とエラーがブラウザのコンソールに出力されます。

requirejsのときは、モジュールの定義はdefineを使い、
HTMLのインラインスクリプトからは、requireを使ってモジュールを読み込んでいました。

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['mymodule'], function(mymodule){
        new mymodule("<?php echo $hoge; ?>");
    });
</script>
```

browserifyではどのようにするのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サンプルコードありがとうございます！

サンプルコードを改造して色々試してみました。
結果、かなりトリッキーですが、browserifyの-rオプションを使わなくても
requireができるようになりました。

- mod/aaa.coffee

  ```
  bbb   = require './bbb'

  module.exports =  class
      constructor: (@name) ->
          console.log 'aaa'
          new bbb();
  ```
- mod/bbb.coffee

  ```
  module.exports = class
      constructor: (@name) ->
          console.log 'bbb'
  ```
- mod/brequire.coffee

  ```
  # ↓全ての自作モジュールをreqruieする。
  require './aaa'
  require './bbb'

  module.exports = (mod) ->

      return require mod
  ```
- application.coffee

  ```
  window.br = require 'mod/brequire'
  ```
- HTML

  ```
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <script>
      var aaa = br("./aaa");
      new aaa();
  </script>
  ```

mod/brequire.coffeeの全ての自作モジュールをrequireするところは、
モジュールを作る度に追加しなくてはいけないので、できれば書きたくないのですが、
ブラウザで実行時にrequireの動的なロードはダメなようで、あらかじめrequireが必要でした。

ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

[`-r` オプション](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires)で外部にエクスポートしたいモジュールを指定します:

```sh
$ cat mymodule.js
module.exports = 'hi';

$ browserify -r ./mymodule.js:mymodule > application.js
$ cat application.js              # ↓ 指定したモジュール
require=(function e(t,n,r){<...>{"mymodule":[function(require,module,exports){
    module.exports = 'hi';
},{}]},{},[]);
```

```html
<script src="application.js"></script>
<script>
  var mymodule = require('mymodule');
</script>
```

指定しない場合は`require=`が出力されず、ブラウザ側から`require`グローバルが使えません:

```sh
$ browserify ./mymodule.js > application.js
$ cat application.js
(function e(t,n,r){<...>
```

Answer (score 1):

私も以前同様の問題にぶつかった経験があります。
サーバがページ表示のタイミングでしか生成できない変数があり、
それをJavascript関数に渡す必要があったのですが、色々試して結局断念した経験があります。
この部分さえ解決できればGulp+Browserifyが実用になりそうなのですが……